# Selecting certain levels of a hierarchy with PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, regex, postgresql

I have a table representing a hierarchy using enumerated paths:

```
  id | name  | path  
-----+-------+-------
   1 | Bob   | 1
   2 | Joe   | 2
   3 | Kyle  | 2/3
   4 | Sarah | 2/4
   5 | Jim   | 5
   6 | Steve | 5/6
   7 | Adam  | 5/7
   8 | Frank | 5/7/8
   9 | Sue   | 5/7/9
```

I need a query that returns the immediate children of a given record, and for each child, the count of all the subrecords underneath it.

For example, a query against Jim (id=5) should return the following set:

```
  id | name  | path  | subrecords
-----+-------+-------+------------
   6 | Steve | 5/6   | 0
   7 | Adam  | 5/7   | 2
```

---

### Attempts:

If I do:

```
select did, name, path, SUBSTRING(path FROM '5\/[^\/]*$') as child_path from items where path ~ '5\/.*';
```

I get part of the way there...

```
 did | name  | path  | child_path 
-----+-------+-------+---------
   6 | Steve | 5/6   | 5/6
   7 | Adam  | 5/7   | 5/7
   8 | Frank | 5/7/8 | 
   9 | Sue   | 5/7/9 |
```

... but records 8 and 9 need to be rolled up as a count under 7.

I tried:

```
select SUBSTRING(path FROM '5\/[^\/]*$') as child_path, COUNT(id) as count from items where path ~ '5\/.*' GROUP BY child_path;
```

Which gets me:

```
child_path | count 
----------+-------
          |     2
 5/7      |     1
 5/6      |     1
```

Nope.

How could I achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can do this without a self-join.

You can select all descendants of a given node with this expression:  `path like '5' || '/' || id || '%'`.  Then, you can aggregate them by choosing the substring up to 5 and the next id:

```
select left(path, length('5'||'/') + position('/' in split_part(path||'/', '5'||'/', 2)) - 1) as child,
       count(*) - 1 as numdescendants
from items
where path like '5' || '/' || '%'
group by child;
```

`count(*)` counts the number of descendants for a particular child, including that child.  Hence, the `- 1` to get the number of their descendants.

This should work so you can replace the `'5'` with any path.

Comment: This is beautiful, thank you! (BTW to clarify for others something that confused me: the double-pipes `||` are string concatenators, not OR operators)

Answer (score 2):

It seems to me this does the job.

```
SELECT i.id,
       i.name,
       i.path,
       count(ii.id) AS cnt
FROM items i
LEFT OUTER JOIN items ii
ON ii.id != i.id AND ii.path LIKE i.path || '%'
WHERE i.path ~ '5\/[^\/]*$'
GROUP BY i.id,
         i.name,
         i.path;
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/b5b4c/23

Comment: @popovitsj- Thank you, this does work- but got to give it to Gordon's join-free solution